# Use Raspberry Pi to stream videos on a TV

Tags: streaming-video

I hoped that I could stream videos like YouTube videos with my Raspberry Pi and watch them on my analog TV. Unfortunately there seems to be no way to use Flash with the Raspberry Pi (or only with [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian)?). Is there a way (except for using [Gnash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnash))?

However, I still have hope, and I am wondering if one might in some way use the Raspberry Pi as a digital-to-analog converter between a laptop and a TV. Maybe with a cable connection or maybe similar to Mac's [AirTunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirTunes) technology?

Comment: What are the connections your computer has, and what connections does your TV accept?

Comment: @syb0rg My Laptop has an VGA exit as well as an HDMI exit. The TV is an older model and accepts RCA and SCART.

Comment: See Raspbmc (youtube plugin) http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=6567 will download the flv and convert for view near real-time.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I have found is to use Steven Hickson's YouTube player. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
git clone git://github.com/StevenHickson/PiAUISuite.git
cd PiAUISuite/Install/
./InstallAUISuite.sh
```

When it runs, it will ask if you want to install each part of the suite one by one. Just say no to all of them apart from the YouTube player.

Then go to YouTube in your browser and click on a video. It automatically plays it at full-screen and the highest quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PiCAST](https://github.com/lanceseidman/PiCAST) for this issue.

- Connect your Raspberry Pi to a TV with [RCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector) or [SCART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART).
- The Linux distribution on Raspberry Pi should have [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) (GUI).
- Install PiCAST.
- PiCAST uses youtube-dl (YouTube downloader [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) program) to download YouTube video as [Flash Video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video) (.flv) files.
- Send the YouTube link with the `ssh` command (the command should be such as: `ssh pi_PI "sh /home/pi/PiCAST/youtube/yt-videograb.sh http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWXzm-wEucg | cryptcat pi_IP 8882 -k secret_key"`)

I can use it with these settings.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi can play [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) streams effortlessly. You just need to find a way to stream the videos as H.264 from your PC.